# Scroll Divs Just Like a Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have 3 divs as below and 3 links as below.

Divs

```
<div id="div1">
   Div 1   
</div>

<div id="div2">
    Div 2 
</div>

<div id="div3">
    Div 3 
</div>
```

Links

```
<a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a id="link3" href="#">Link 2</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is create a slider. When I

click on the link1 -> show div 1

click on the link2 -> show div 2

click on the link3 -> show div 3

Also I'm trying to make it operate just as a slider. In a slider it has got only prev and next links where here I have multiple link. For each link there will be a respective div.

JsFiddle links is : http://jsfiddle.net/n4p4x/1/

Can you please tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: jquery UI > Accordion?

Comment: are you want to make this with your code? or you can implement your code in  any kind of slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this check this below code and 
fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/n4p4x/2/

it is solve your problem? 
let me know 
i have done according to what i understand by your question.

```
#main{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:960px;
    margin:50px auto 0;
}
#main div{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**html**

```
<a id="link1" href="#">Link 1</a><br/>
<a id="link2" href="#">Link 2</a><br/>
<a id="link3" href="#">Link 2</a>

<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="main">
    <div id="div1">
        Div 1 - In feugiat cursus velit et accumsan. Morbi eu ligula ac libero vestibulum molestie eget in diam. Fusce quis urna sit amet metus accumsan consectetur a quis odio. Donec tempor hendrerit mauris at venenatis. Etiam eu nisi ligula, eu viverra eros. Pellentesque vehicula ultricies consectetur. Praesent vehicula libero sit amet nulla sollicitudin placerat. Praesent eu elit arcu. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis justo pharetra id dictum felis auctor. Integer dapibus luctus dictum. Morbi pellentesque sagittis faucibus. Phasellus placerat semper malesuada. Praesent pulvinar tristique urna, ut sollicitudin dui convallis mollis. Praesent cursus venenatis risus, nec adipiscing sapien rhoncus in.   
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        Div 2 - In feugiat cursus velit et accumsan. Morbi eu ligula ac libero vestibulum molestie eget in diam. Fusce quis urna sit amet metus accumsan consectetur a quis odio. Donec tempor hendrerit mauris at venenatis. Etiam eu nisi ligula, eu viverra eros. Pellentesque vehicula ultricies consectetur. Praesent vehicula libero sit amet nulla sollicitudin placerat. Praesent eu elit arcu. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis justo pharetra id dictum felis auctor. Integer dapibus luctus dictum. Morbi pellentesque sagittis faucibus. Phasellus placerat semper malesuada. Praesent pulvinar tristique urna, ut sollicitudin dui convallis mollis. Praesent cursus venenatis risus, nec adipiscing sapien rhoncus in.   
    </div>

    <div id="div3">
        Div 3 - In feugiat cursus velit et accumsan. Morbi eu ligula ac libero vestibulum molestie eget in diam. Fusce quis urna sit amet metus accumsan consectetur a quis odio. Donec tempor hendrerit mauris at venenatis. Etiam eu nisi ligula, eu viverra eros. Pellentesque vehicula ultricies consectetur. Praesent vehicula libero sit amet nulla sollicitudin placerat. Praesent eu elit arcu. Nullam tincidunt tortor quis justo pharetra id dictum felis auctor. Integer dapibus luctus dictum. Morbi pellentesque sagittis faucibus. Phasellus placerat semper malesuada. Praesent pulvinar tristique urna, ut sollicitudin dui convallis mollis. Praesent cursus venenatis risus, nec adipiscing sapien rhoncus in.   
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must style your div's

```
 <div id="main">
      <div class="slice" id="slide_1"></div><div class="slice" id="slide_2"></div><div class="slice" id="slide_3"></div>

    </div>
    #main{
    position:relative;
}
    .slice{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

The most important is: float:left; try it

check out my own scroller: http://dap.ntua.gr/el
http://dap.ntua.gr/el/template/js/scroller.js